# SwiftUI's NavigationLink `tag` and `selection` in NavigationView stops working if not all NavigationLinks are displayed

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a list of items in a `Form` in a `NavigationView`, each having a detail-view that can be reached with `NavigationLink`.
When I add a new element to the list, I want to show its detail-view. For that I use a `@State var currentSelection` that the `NavigationLink` receives as `selection`, and each element has functions as the `tag`:

```swift
NavigationLink(
  destination: DetailView(entry: entry),
  tag: entry,
  selection: $currentSelection,
  label: { Text("The number \(entry)") })
```

This works, and it follows the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) and the [best practises](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui).

The surprise is, that it **stops** working when the list has more elements than fit on screen (plus ~2). Question: Why? And how can I work around it?

---

I made a minimal example to replicate the behaviour:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entries = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    @State var currentSelection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(entries.sorted(), id: \.self) { entry in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(entry: entry),
                        tag: entry,
                        selection: $currentSelection,
                        label: { Text("The number \(entry)") })
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarLeading) { Button("Add low") {
                    let newEntry = (entries.min() ?? 1) - 1
                    entries.insert(newEntry, at: 1)
                    currentSelection = newEntry
                } }
                ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) { Button("Add high") {
                    let newEntry = (entries.max() ?? 50) + 1
                    entries.append(newEntry)
                    currentSelection = newEntry
                } }
                ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.bottomBar) {
                    Text("The current selection is \(String(describing: currentSelection))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let entry: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("It's a \(entry)!")
    }
}
```

(I ruled out that the *number* of elements is the core problem by reducing the list to 5 items and setting a padding on the label: `label: { Text("The number \(entry).padding(30)") })`)

As you can see in the screen-recordings, after reaching the critical number of elements (either by prepending or appending to the list), the bottom sheet still shows that the `currentSelection` is being updated, but no navigation is happening.

I used iOS 14.7.1, Xcode 12.5.1 and Swift 5.

[image: adding to the start of the list]
[image: adding to the end of the list]

Comment: From a UX point of view, you may want to scroll to the newly created navigation link (using ScrollViewReader), so it becomes visible. I would guess, the programmatic fired navigation link will then work.

Comment: I like the idea  I couldn't get it to work with _my_ approach, but I'll include it in the ZStack-Solution.

Comment: Just added a solution, but be careful with it. ;)

Comment: check out my updated answer, I made it look a little prettier by moving out navigation ling creation login into extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because lower items are not rendered, so in the hierarchy there's no `NavigationLink` with such tag

I suggest you using an `ZStack` + `EmptyView` `NavigationLink` "hack".

Also I'm using LazyView here, thanks to `@autoclosure` it lets me pass upwrapped `currentSelection`: this will only be called when `NavigationLink` is active, and this is happens when `currentSelection != nil`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entries = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    @State var currentSelection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                EmptyNavigationLink(
                    destination: { DetailView(entry: $0) },
                    selection: $currentSelection
                )
                Form {
                    ForEach(entries.sorted(), id: \.self) { entry in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(entry: entry),
                            label: { Text("The number \(entry)") })
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarLeading) { Button("Add low") {
                        let newEntry = (entries.min() ?? 1) - 1
                        entries.insert(newEntry, at: 1)
                        currentSelection = newEntry
                    } }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) { Button("Add high") {
                        let newEntry = (entries.max() ?? 50) + 1
                        entries.append(newEntry)
                        currentSelection = newEntry
                    } }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.bottomBar) {
                        Text("The current selection is \(String(describing: currentSelection))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let entry: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("It's a \(entry)!")
    }
}

public struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    private let build: () -> Content
    public init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    public var body: Content {
        build()
    }
}

struct EmptyNavigationLink<Destination: View>: View {
    let lazyDestination: LazyView<Destination>
    let isActive: Binding<Bool>
    
    init<T>(
        @ViewBuilder destination: @escaping (T) -> Destination,
        selection: Binding<T?>
    )  {
        lazyDestination = LazyView(destination(selection.wrappedValue!))
        isActive = .init(
            get: { selection.wrappedValue != nil },
            set: { isActive in
                if !isActive {
                    selection.wrappedValue = nil
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: lazyDestination,
            isActive: isActive,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )
    }
}
```

Check out more about [LazyView](https://github.com/joehinkle11/Lazy-View-SwiftUI), it helps often with `NavigationLink`: in real apps destination may be a huge screen, and when you have a `NavigationLink` in each cell SwiftUI will process all of them which may lead to lags

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes from the programmatic navigation (launched by the buttons in the toolbar)
Your NavigationLink needs to exist in order to be triggered.

But if a `List` is used (or a Form, or a LazyVStack), children view (here : `NavigationLink`s) that are not supposed to appear on the screen are not "created". Therefore when you try to fire the NavigationLink (modifying the currentSelection), this NavigationLink may not exist

If we replace the List / Form with a ScrollView the problem should disappear.

But the best approach is certainly to separate the two ways to navigate :

1- programatic navigation, triggered by the Buttons. For that we'll use the `NavigationLink(_:destination:isActive:)` initializer.

2- navigation via the List (tappable cells, aka `NavigationLink(destination:label:`)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entries = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    @State var currentSelection: Int? = nil
    @State var linkIsActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(entries.sorted(), id: \.self) { entry in
                    // 2- Clickable label
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(entry: entry),
                        label: { Text("The number \(entry)") })
                }
            }
            .background(
                // 1- Programmatic navigation
                NavigationLink("", destination: DetailView(entry: currentSelection ?? -99), isActive: $linkIsActive)
            )
            .onChange(of: currentSelection, perform: { value in
                if value != nil {
                    linkIsActive = true
                }
            })
            .onChange(of: linkIsActive, perform: { value in
                if !value {
                    currentSelection = nil
                }
            })
   //...
}
```

Comment: Nice!   The differences to @Philip's solution are (1) using `.background()` instead of `ZStack`, (2) making `isActive` an explicit `@State var` and using `onChange()` instead of a `Binding` and (3) a `??`-fallback instead of the `!` — although in a real app a fallback is a bit harder to create.

Comment: To be honest I think I prefer @Philip's solution. :)
 
1- background and ZStack, it's the same
3- he can force unwrap because he uses LazyView.
2- the real difference. This solution might be more readable for some people (onChange vs custom Binding), so I'll leave it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As it may be desired to see which row has been added to the form. I would like to show a solution which first scrolls to the newly inserted item, then shows the detail view.

It's not my favourite animation or flow, though.

The solution adds an additional ScrollViewReader which seems to work flawlessly with Forms, too. The view where we want to scroll-to, is the NavigationLink (the Label won't work, since it is not instantiated when not shown).

**Caution**

I occasionally encountered some glitches, which may be Playgrounds. Also, on Xcode 13 beta 4, there's warning issued in the console indicating that there is an issue with NavigationLink, and we should file a bug report. Well ...

My suspicion is that there might be an issue when performing the scroll animation and subsequently the push navigation. Needs more investigation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entries = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    @State var currentSelection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                Form {
                    ForEach(entries.sorted(), id: \.self) { entry in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(entry: entry),
                            tag: entry,
                            selection: $currentSelection,
                            label: { Text("The number \(entry)") }
                        )
                        .id("-\(entry)-")
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: currentSelection) { newValue in
                    withAnimation {
                        if let currentSelection = self.currentSelection {
                            proxy.scrollTo("-\(currentSelection)-")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarLeading) { Button("Add low") {
                        let newEntry = (entries.min() ?? 1) - 1
                        entries.insert(newEntry, at: 1)
                        currentSelection = newEntry
                    } }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarTrailing) { Button("Add high") {
                        let newEntry = (entries.max() ?? 50) + 1
                        entries.append(newEntry)
                        currentSelection = newEntry
                    } }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.bottomBar) {
                        Text("The current selection is \(String(describing: currentSelection))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let entry: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("It's a \(entry)!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but starting with the third new element, it stops working:
* add high, back, scroll up
* add high, back, scroll up
* add high: stays with `Optional(28)`
* scroll up, add high: `selection is nil` 

Comment: @JannikArndt I had some issues in Playgrounds as described. But I couldn't reproduce your issue on Version 13.0 beta 4 (13A5201i). My suspicion is, we need to clearly separate the two animations, and only start the navigation when the scroll animation is finished. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to start some continuation after an animation is complete, like in UIKit. But there is a solution at least! And I will check out this later. ;)